# Searching for an exact repeated sequence (and removing all duplicates) using a PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will find an exact repeating pattern (case-sensitive).  For instance, middle initials in a name string. Examples:

- Jim G G Bob  is a match on " G " x 2
- Jim G. G. Bob is a match on " G. " x 2
- Tom H H H Ford is a match on " H " x 3 and so on ...
- Sarah H Howard is NOT a match because we have "h ", "H ", and " H" (which are all unique)

I only want to keep the 1st occurrence and remove all others. What will find and remove exact duplicates?

Comment: why change a valid name?

Comment: ^ the periods, bring up a whole new issue also

Comment: Hi Pat. There's a general expectation that posters ought to show what they have tried prior to bringing the problem here. If you have some code, please do edit it into the question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I'll post more details / sample code in any future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in `php`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\b([a-zA-Z]\W+)\1+/u', '$1', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qiNd4L/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b           # word boundary
(            # capturing group #1 start
   pL        # match a single unicode letter 
   \W+       # match 1 or more non-word character
)            # capturing group #1 start
\1+          # match 1 or more of captured group #1 to match *repeats*
```

Comment: Thank you kindly -- this regex worked perfectly.  I'm not proficient in regex and appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex way to solve this general problem: `explode` on space and loop over the resulting array, `unset`ting each key where the value is the same as the previous, then `implode` to form the sequential-duplicate-free string.

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$previous = null;
foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $previous) unset($words[$key]);
    $previous = $value;
}
$string = implode(' ', $words);
```

Comment: Thank you kindly !